# How to have Google Sheets auto sort by colour?

Tags: google-sheets

I have been tasked with creating a spreadsheet for my workplace that has multiple information on it, regarding cars, MOT date etc., IMO I have a decent spreadsheet working that will auto change colour based on the data that is in a certain cell.

However, I cannot figure out how I can auto sort the colours in a specific order, see link for example:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I1-NcFbGS-r1I1pTdY2on7py7i1yG6BoiWcGq48gBes/edit#gid=0

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. The filter feature includes a "Sort by color" that allows to  select one color of the used on the filter range. Please show what you tried and add more details about the specific order that you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a filter, you should be able to "Sort by color" > "Fill Color". You'll have to sort it a couple times to get the exact order you want, but it'll group up the colors.